# Composite Attributes in apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am learning database in apex oracle. 
Now I am trying to create table. 
I Have composite attributes, but I cannot implement on db.

```
  CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR2(15)  NOT NULL,
    SSN NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
    BIRTHDATE DATE,
    AGE NUMBER(3),
    GENDER VARCHAR2(6),
);
```

[image: --]

Answer (score 2):

Not all logical attributes have to be present in the physical model, as you can easily produce them while querying data:

```
SELECT firstname || ' ' || lastname AS fullname
FROM person
```

If you insist on implementing it as a column, you could use a generated (computed) column:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME VARCHAR2(15)  NOT NULL,
FULLNAME VARCHAR2(31) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (FIRSTNAME || ' ' || LASTNAME) VIRTUAL, 
...
```

For completeness I should mention that you could also create a user-defined [object type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm) with `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME` as its attributes, but I personally think that you shouldn't go that route for portability and maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the composite attribute clause you have in there but your table can be created simply by removing the last comma in the attribute list and removing everything after the semi-colon.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
LASTNAME VARCHAR2(15)  NOT NULL,
SSN NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
BIRTHDATE DATE,
AGE NUMBER(3),
GENDER VARCHAR2(6)
);
```